# Why did ID3D11Device::CreateInputLayout fail with E_INVALIDARG?

Tags: c++, winapi, shader, directx-11, msdn

I am writing a programm in C++ using DirectX11. Now I wanted to start with shaders and for that I also need the ID3D11InputLayout. Because I want to give choices for later use. I have two vertex structs to pass in to the VertexShader:

```
typedef struct _Vertex1
{
    XMFLOAT3 Pos;
    XMFLOAT4 Color;
} VertexPosColor;
typedef struct _Vertex2
{
    XMFLOAT3 Pos;
    XMFLOAT3 Normal;
    XMFLOAT2 Tex0;
    XMFLOAT2 Tex1;
};
```

And no I'm creating the ID3D11InputLayouts like follows:

```
// Create INPUTLAYOUT 1
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC vertex1Desc[] =
{
    {"POSITION", 0U, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0U, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0U},
    {"COLOR", 0U, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0U, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0U},
};
hr = GInterface::m_d3dDevice->CreateInputLayout(vertex1Desc, 2U, pVertexBlob->GetBufferPointer(), pVertexBlob->GetBufferSize(), &GInterface::m_d3dInputLayouts[0]);
if (FAILED(hr)) {
    EErrors::printError(L"Failed to create input layout 1!", L"Pipeline Error", L"CreateInputLayout", EEE_D3D11, hr);
    return false;
}

// Create INPUTLAYOUT 2
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC vertex2Desc[] =
{
    {"POSITION", 0U, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0U, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0U},
    {"NORMAL", 0U, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0U, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0U},
    {"TEXCOORD", 0U, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0U, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0U},
    {"TEXCOORD", 1U, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0U, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0U},
};
hr = GInterface::m_d3dDevice->CreateInputLayout(vertex2Desc, 4U, pVertexBlob->GetBufferPointer(), pVertexBlob->GetBufferSize(), &GInterface::m_d3dInputLayouts[1]);
if (FAILED(hr)) {
    EErrors::printError(L"Failed to create input layout 2!", L"Pipeline Error", L"CreateInputLayout", EEE_D3D11, hr);
    return false;
}
```

The first call of the CreateInputLayout function succeeds, but the second returns an E_INVALIDARG HRESULT.
I don't know why...

The variable for the InputLayouts is static and initialized like follows:

```
ID3D11InputLayout** GInterface::m_d3dInputLayouts = (ID3D11InputLayout**)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(ID3D11InputLayout*) * GInterface::m_d3dInputLayoutsAmount);
```

I appreciate any answers, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same shader bytecode appears to be passed as input to `CreateInputLayout`. So the same input layout is expected which does not match the declared `D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC` descriptors. If you expect to be using different input layouts, each must be created with a matching shader.